# Coreml: How to add two tensors on slices?

Tags: python, numpy, coreml, coremltools

I have two tensors: a.shape = [1, 3, 80, 80, 2] and b.shape = [1, 3, 80, 80, 19] and I only want to add b[..., 0:2] + a using the coreml model builder.

Something like this

```
b[..., 0:2] = (b[..., 0:2] * 2. - 0.5 + a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice b into two parts, modify the 0:2 slice, then concatenate this back with the other slice of b into a (1, 3, 80, 80, 19) tensor.

Comment: I figure it out thanks to your tutorials. I'll put the link here https://machinethink.net/blog/mobilenet-ssdlite-coreml/. Awesome work, thank you

Comment: one more thing. Do I need to permute the [1, 3, 80, 80, 19] so it will be [19, 80, 80, 3, 1] and then do the slicing and permute it back? From my understanding slicing works only on the first axis (or maybe I do not know how to specify the axis on which to do the slicing)

Comment: Try the `SliceStatic` layer, which is more powerful than the old slice layer.